# Facing a fatal exception of while creating JSONObject with base64 string in Android

Tags: java, android, json

Hi below is the exact exception that I am facing while creating the JSONObject and adding base64 string of a document

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1040KB
       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:203)
       at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:354)
       at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:261)
       at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:733)
       at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:246)
       at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:616)
       at org.json.JSONArray.toString(JSONArray.java:587)
       at com.attech.attech_android_1.driq.OnboardingPathwayModule.Activities.PathwayActivity$2.getParams(PathwayActivity.java:959)
       at com.attech.attech_android_1.driq.NetworkCalls.VolleyMultipartRequest.getBody(VolleyMultipartRequest.java:61)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:245)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:219)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:97)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

The line on which exception is according is

```
jsonObject.put("value", mList.get(i).getBase64String());
```

And this is the exception that i am getting on executing line while debuging as well

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()
```

Comment: And... What is the question?

Comment: get to know that why this exception is throwing and how to resolve it